Are sets with no limit points not compact?
Let $A$ be some set of some metric space. I am wondering whether it is true that if $A$ has no limit points, then $A$ is not compact?
If $A$ has no limit points, then $A$ cannot be sequentially compact because for any sequence made of points in $A$, there is no convergent subsequence. So $A$ cannot be compact. Is that correct?

No, consider the empty set (or a set of finitely many elements). The empty set has no limit points, but any open cover has a finite subcover.
Also, re sequential compactness, consider the set with only one element. For any sequence whose elements are in the set, there is a convergent subsequence, because the only possible sequence is that same element repeated over and over.

If $A$ is a finite set, then it is still compact. For your assertion to hold good, there should be an infinite sequence of distinct points in the given set. As pointed out by coffeemath, this can happen if the set you consider is infinite and unbounded.
